# Expressing the square of sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
\lvert \sum_{y \epsilon K}^{} \frac{1+y}{-y^3+y^2-y+1}\rvert^2
$$
I'm a little bit confused about how to expand the square of a sum. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Calculate the sum first, then take its absolute value, then square it. Any possible expansion here was made impossible after taking the absolute value.

Comment: Since $|u|^2=u^2$, you can actually replace the absolue value with parentheses.